# How to parse private Objective-C specific Mach-O sections

Tags: objective-c, mach-o

In the DATA segment of a Mach-O binary, there are a few objective-C specific sections (mentioned on page 7 of the [Mach-O file format](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Mach-O_File_Format.pdf))

To quote the [PiOS paper](http://www.iseclab.org/papers/egele-ndss11.pdf):

> the __objc_classlist section contains a list of all classes whose
>   implementation is present in the analyzed binary (that is, all classes
>   implemented by the developer or included by the static linker)

and

> The __objc_classref section, on the other hand, contains references to
>   all classes that are used by the application. The implementations of
>   these classes need not be contained in the binary itself, but may be
>   provided by the runtime framework (the equivalent of
>   dynamically-linked libraries).

They mention that the layout of these structure is available from the Objective C runtime headers (which are available [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/runtime/)).

What are the actual structures of the `__objc_classref` and `__objc_classlist` sections?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of the `GETSECT` macro in a [slightly newer version of the Objective-C runtime implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/objc-file.mm). It looks like so:

```
#define GETSECT(name, type, sectname)                                   \
    type *name(const header_info *hi, size_t *outCount)  \
    {                                                                   \
        unsigned long byteCount = 0;                                    \
        type *data = (type *)                                           \
            getsectiondata(hi->mhdr, SEG_DATA, sectname, &byteCount);   \
        *outCount = byteCount / sizeof(type);                           \
        return data;                                                    \
    }
```

This tells us that each section is an array of items of type `type`.

It's used a few lines later to declare functions named `_getObjc2ClassRefs` and `_getObjc2ClassList` which read the two sections that you're interested in:

```
GETSECT(_getObjc2ClassRefs,           class_t *,       "__objc_classrefs");
GETSECT(_getObjc2ClassList,           classref_t,       "__objc_classlist");
```

So `__objc_classrefs` contains `class_t *`s, and `__objc_classlist` contains `classref_t`s. Interpreting those fields should be relatively self-explanatory.